# Windows 10: While highlighting text it ends up getting drag and dropped before I can finish highlighting

Tags: windows, mouse, highlighting, drag-and-drop

I'm using Windows 10 and am finding myself in a very frustrating situation.  I'm hoping it's just a setting I accidentally turned on, but I cannot find a solution or good description of exactly what's happening so I figured I would ask here.

Basically if I'm in the middle of selecting text that is editable: Email drafts, URLs in every browser I have, Notepad, Sublime Text, Word, PowerPoint, etc. if I slow down for half a millisecond than the speed I was highlighting at it will take the already highlighted text I have and cut and paste/drag and drop it into the location where my cursor is.

Example:

Text I start with:

**This is a sample sentence that I would like to highlight only a portion of to be able to copy and paste it into another location.  But when I start highlighting and I slow down even for a second the already highlighted text is then drag and dropped to the location where the cursor is.**

Then I start highlighting from the bottom up.  When I do that my cursor is often a line or two above what's being highlighted and that's where the highlighted text gets moved and dropped in to.

Text I end up:

**This is a sample sent** *art highlighting and I slow down even for a second the already highlighted text is then drag and dropped to the location where the cursor is.* **ence that I would like to highlight only a portion of to be able to copy and paste it into another location.  But when I st**

It is getting extremely annoying.  I now can only successfully highlight things by using the shift button and arrow keys and it takes forever.

Hopefully this was descriptive enough to have someone point me in the right direction.

---

**EDIT**

Setup:

- Touchscreen Laptop connected to two 24-inch monitors with the lid shut
- External Bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Comment: Highlight and then use Copy  /  Paste.   That will be significantly more reliable.

Comment: @John That's the problem.  I can't without it taking half the text I'm in the middle of highlighting and moving it halfway up the document to where my cursor is.

Comment: Are you using a mouse or laptop trackpad? If it's a mouse have you tried using a different one, in case there's an issue there with it not registering that you're maintaining the mouse click the entire time? If a trackpad, have you tried using a mouse and seeing if the same happens?

Comment: There is not any issue like that on my Windows 10 or 11 machines here. Try running DISM / SFC (although I have my doubts)  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: It's happening with both mouse and track pad and different mice.  It seems like a feature of windows.  One thing I thought of is that it is a touchscreen laptop.  Maybe there is some sort of pressure sensitive setting or drag and drop feature I can disable, but I haven't been able to find it.  In terms of my setup, the laptop is connected to 2 x 24" monitors and the lid is shut.

Comment: Try a different *cabled* mouse (yes I've read you also tried the trackpad). The only situation I experienced something similar was when the contacts of the left mouse button were broken and apparently stopped sending the pressed-state continously, hence sending the signal UP which led to files/folders being dropped unintensionally or being unable to select anything.-

Comment: Most probably hardware issue, *or* some software which imitates clicks (like [this](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-objects/simulating/mouse-actions.html)). Or *another* mouse or other input device (even virtual) may interfere. Or even gamepad driver which "limits the mouse down period". All in all, this is *not* the normally configurable system behavior, it must be caused by some mechanism external to Windows.